# Связка Spring - Hibernate проблемы с деплоем

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc, dao

В данный момент занимаюсь написанием веб телефонной книги, в рамках закрепления навыков Hibernate и постепенного изучения Spring Framework. Ситуация сложилась такова, что во время деплоя варника через Tomcаt выбивает ошибку:

> **javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
> servletController threw exception**
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/servletController-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
> Unable to instantiate default tuplizer
> [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
>
> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default
> tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter

ранее с подобным не сталкивался.В чем проблема, коллеги?. Заранее благодарен... Код ключевых классов приложен.

servletController-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
               xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
               xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
               xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
               xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
               xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
               xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
               xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
               xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/webapp/jsp"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ua.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/postschema"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class SSController {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SSController.class);

    private PostDAO postDAO;

    private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;

    @RequestMapping (value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allList (){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        List<Post> posts = postDAO.getAll();
        List<Category> categories = categoryDAO.getAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("posts", posts);
        modelAndView.addObject("categories", categories);
        modelAndView.setViewName("posts");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

DAOImpl

```
public abstract class AbstractDAOImplementation<G> implements AbstractDao<G> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void create(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public G edit(G entity) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return entity;
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public G getById(long id) {
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       G entity = getEntityById(session, id);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return entity;
    }
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<G> getAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<G> result = getAllEntity(session);
        return result;
    }

    public abstract G getEntityById (Session session, long id);

    public abstract List<G> getAllEntity(Session session);
}
```

PostDAO

```
public class PostDAO extends AbstractDAOImplementation<Post> {
    @Override
    public Post getEntityById(Session session, long id) {
        Post result = (Post) session.createQuery("from Post where id="+id);
        return result;
    }
 
    @Override
    public List<Post> getAllEntity(Session session) {
        List<Post> result = session.createQuery("from Post ").list();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас же в стектрейсе написано:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/util/proxy/MethodFilter
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter

Добавьте в проект **javassist**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Данный ответ есть решением данного исключения., но возникло новое. Создать новую тему или в этой можете ответить?

Comment: Если ответ является решением описанной проблемы, то создавайте, новую, конечно. Здесь принято давать ответ на конкретный вопрос, чтобы зафиксировать его решение, а не собирать несколько проблем в одном треде.